# Access Forms - Catch 22 trying to insert data to multiple related tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm new to Access but have many years experience using "enterprise" databases.  I'm having trouble implementing a simple task and suspect that my preconceptions are causing me to miss the point so I'm asking for some help.

The simple task is using Access forms for Data Entry that populates two tables:  Customer and CustomerAddress (can be multiple addresses per customer).

The Customer table has primary key CustomerID.  The CustomerAddress table has primary key CustomerAddressID and CustomerID as a foreign key with RI on that relationship.

Form1 is bound to the Customer table.   After entering info for various fields, the user can click a button to display Form2 which is bound to CustomerAddress and enables data entry for multiple addresses.

Form1 passes the CustomerID (assigned by Access) to Form2.  Form2 is not a subform due to size but it could be if that would solve the problem.

In a perfect world, I would want all the new data from both Form1 and Form2 to be committed together.  Presumably I could do this using unbound forms and code the insert statements inside a single transaction.

**Question 1:**  Is there a way to do this using bound forms?

If I use Form1 without ever clicking the "Address" button then a row is successfully added to the Customer table.  The problem comes when trying to add CustomerAddress row(s) in Form2 before the Customer row has been added to the table.

In Form2, if the CustomerID is not used, then there is an insert error because a CustomerAddress row cannot be added without a CustomerID.
If the CustomerID is used, then there is an insert error because the CustomerID does not exist on the Customer table yet (although the ID appears to have been "reserved").

It's not practical to force the Customer row to be added before opening Form2 as some Customer required fields are not present at that point in the workflow.

**Question 2:**  Is there a way round this?  It seems like a common requirement.

I could work around this by removing the RI so that the CustomerAddress rows can be added first, but this seems poor DB design and I'd also need clean-up logic for the case where the Customer add is subsequently cancelled.

As mentioned, I'm probably missing the point and there's a better approach.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would have the same problem regardless of which RDBMS you used if you are enforcing referential integrity. The CustomerID needs to exist in the Customer table before a record can exist in the CustomerAddress table. I'm guessing that CustomerID is an autonumber. What is probably confusing is that Access does immediately 'reserve' an autonumber as soon as a new record is started. However, it does not exist in the Customer table. If that record is never saved, that autonumber value is lost and the next record would get the next number. Requiring an address to be completed before saving the Customer record, sounds like a design problem. It doesn't seem logical. Personally, I would re-think the design. That said, one solution would be to create a temp table for addresses and bind your CustomerAddress form to that. Then, when the customer record is saved, you would run an append query to add the new addresses to the CustomerAddress table. Remember, though, that if a user enters some addresses and the Customer record is never saved, all of that data entry is lost.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  The reason I asked the question is that other RDBMS I've used do have a solution to this problem.  i.e. add rows to different tables within a single transaction.  The DBMS returns the auto-generated key as each record is inserted, but the change only becomes permanent when committed.
You suggestion re temp tables is helpful - thanks.  I don't quite agree there's a design issue here -  adding rows to multiple tables in the same transaction is very common in a normalised database.  However, it does show that I need to modify my approach to how I use Access.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can insert into two tables within a transaction in Access. Within that transaction the parent record must still be inserted before the detail record. However, that is not your case. You are trying to do it with two separate unrelated bound forms. There is no single transaction involved. You would need to do that via code.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your statement:

> It's not practical to force the Customer row to be added before opening Form2 as some Customer required fields are not present at that point in the workflow.

You are correct that you won't be able to insert the Customer row if the "required but not yet known" fields have their `Required` property set to `Yes` (i.e., NOT NULL). However, with Access 2010 and later you could use an event-driven data macro to make such fields "not required" on Insert but "required" on Update. In your case, you could

- allow the Customer record to be inserted without the "eventually required" fields,
- allow the addition of CustomerAddress records (with RI enabled), and then
- re-open the Customer record for updating, with the data macro now enforcing the "required" status of the other fields.

The Before Change data macro might look something like this:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

Comment: Thanks - I'll bear that approach in mind and I learned a few things from your sample macros.   At the moment, the thought of adding a row to a table without required fields is a step too far for me.   I'm still coming to grips with some of the compromises required to use Access.

Comment: I'm not sure what other DBMS(s) you're thinking of, but at least with SQL Server you still can't INSERT a row - even inside a TRANSACTION - that omits NOT NULL columns (T-SQL sample [here](http://pastebin.com/KfWCTQFe)). And, if you can't insert the parent row then you can't SELECT @@IDENTITY so you can't insert the child rows. Therefore you're still grappling with issues that are in no way specific to Access databases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies within your Question 1. Yes there is a way to do this with bound forms, and would be the approach I would use.

Form1 is bound to the Customer table. Add Form 2 onto Form 1 as a subform. Select / highlight Form 2, goto the properties sheet. On the Data tab, set the Link Master Field to CustomerID and Link Child Fields to CustomerID.

Then after any action taken on Form 1, requery Form 2.

I think this will get you started and at least should give you an idea on how to proceed once completed.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why both must be or one would even want to submit both customer and a record from the child table at the same time.

What about when you want to add an additional address, then that add address button and code now will have to check + test if the main customer already exists, and use separate logic to deal if the customer record exists, or does not. And what about if a user has entered the customer name and info, and does not yet have the address as the customer on the phone might have just moved and has to call back with the new address. I can think of another half dozen cases in which building a design in which both customer and customer address records MUST be added at the same time.

As others noted, you going to have this issue with any relational database, including Access. I should also point out that Access works EXACTLY the same here if you use Access as a front end to SQL server or Oracle.

So it makes little sense to build a different UI and coding process for adding the customer and the address, and then a DIFFERENT set of rules and UI for adding additional address over time. So build a form to search + find a customer, and add that customer and display that customer. Once that process is done, then you add the process (and UI part) to allow the user to view, or add address to that customer. I don’t think I ever seen a UI with separate forms to add/edit customer and a separate form to allow additional address to have some requirement that they are submitted together at the same time.

If the user bails out of the Address because they realize the address is not available, wrong etc., this should not suggest that the customer information entered so far be dumped and not added. If the user after bailing from adding the address (say close or cancel that form), then you return to the customer form. If the user decides at that point in time for some strange reason they do NOT want the customer in the system anymore, then provide a delete button.

If the business rules are that one MUST ALWAYS have at least one address in all cases, then upon closing the customer form you don’t allow the form to be closed and request that that user enter at least one address for this user. And perhaps they bumped or hit the wrong key to exit the address enter part – no need to penalize that user and force them to re-enter the customer info. So don’t let them exit the customer form until they enter an address or provide them (suggest to the user) they can delete/remove the customer fi they want to exit.

If you use a form + sub form setup, then zero code is required for the relational part. And a tab control gets you both forms can be near full screen size. (no need to launch a separate form).

Of course you could write a bunch of code and placed everything in a transaction, but such is a waste of coding time for no benefits and amounts to theft of company hours and time when not required.